# How to import Ordnance Survery raster layer to ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, import, ordnance-survey, united-kingdom

I have downloaded raster map data from ONS, the data has come in the form of two files... one is full of  .tlw files and the other is full of .tab files...

How do I import it into a raster layer to ArcCatalog?

Comment: Tab files are normally vector based but may have raster overlays in them. the *.tlw should be the "world" file which helps to geolocate the data. Without a third party (FME suite, or MapInfo, or data interoperability esri extension) you are probably not going be able to do anything.

Comment: Is this particular "raster map data" available as open data to download so that we can test and advise?

Answer (score 1):

What you need are the .tif files and the .tfw files. You bring both of these files into the same folder and then you can import the .tif files on ArcCatalog.